# How to find, what kind of a Javascript error I have?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quick and a silly question that got me confused.

What kind of error occurs if I use an assignment statement instead of a comparison statement? I  need to check if the value of the counter variable is equal to 5.

The code:

```
if (counter = 5) { /* ==SOME CODE==*/}
```

VS

```
if (counter == 5) { /* ==SOME CODE==*/}
```

Comment: the condition will be the value after assignment, no error will occur, if you assign counter to false or null then the block won't work, otherwise the block will.

Comment: using the first code above, counter will be set to 5 and SOME CODE is run .... there won't be an error ... in the second code, SOME CODE will run if counter == 5 (or "5")

Comment: So the second code would be a run time error?

Comment: Also, to be safe, use `===`. It will ensure your types match as well.

Comment: An error will only occur if `counter` is declared as `const`.

Comment: But I need to check if the value of the counter variable is equal to 5.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pick-up this problem is to reverse the order of the comparison.

Instead of:

`if (someVar == 5)`

Use:

`if (5 == someVar)`

This way, if you mess it up, you'll get an assignment error, since you can't assign a different value to the number 5. You *can* assign a different value to a number object that happens to *hold* the number 5, but you can't change the 5 itself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of error occurs if I use an assignment statement instead of a comparison statement?

In your example i assume that a browser would not throw any errors.
I tested https://validatejavascript.com/ with this code:

```
let counter = 3;

if (counter = 5) {
  alert('Will this ever show or always?');
}
```

A linter might generate a warning - for exmaple

- [validatejavascript.com](https://validatejavascript.com/) threw: `3:5 error Unexpected assignment within an 'if' statement. (no-cond-assign)` and
- [jshint.com](https://jshint.com/) threw: `Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.`

And based on your comment:

> But I need to check if the value of the counter variable is equal to 5.

A [simple assignment operator (=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) is used to assign a value to a variable.

What you are looking for are operators for [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

> JavaScript provides three different value-comparison operations:
>
> ```
> === - Strict Equality Comparison ("strict equality", "identity", "triple equals")
> == - Abstract Equality Comparison ("loose equality", "double equals")
> Object.is provides SameValue (new in ES2015).
> ```
>
> Which operation you choose depends on what sort of comparison you are
> looking to perform. Briefly:
>
> 1. double equals (==) will perform a type conversion
>    when comparing two things, and will handle NaN, -0, and +0
>    specially to conform to IEEE 754 (so NaN != NaN, and -0 == +0);
> 2. triple equals (===) will do the same comparison as double equals
>    (including the special handling for NaN, -0, and +0)
>    but without type conversion; if the types differ, false is returned.
> 3. Object.is does no type conversion and no special handling for NaN, -0,
>    and +0 (giving it the same behavior as === except on those special
>    numeric values).
>
> Note that the distinction between these all have to do with their
> handling of primitives; none of them compares whether the parameters
> are conceptually similar in structure. For any non-primitive objects x
> and y which have the same structure but are distinct objects
> themselves, all of the above forms will evaluate to false.